# suspend maya python excecution, then continue

Tags: python, maya

I have this wierd thing where Maya says an attribute doesn’t exist when I try to change it’s value.
The reason is that Maya just created that attribute in the script and hasn’t updated the attribute “list”/”interface” yet. 
Is there a way to make maya pause the script excecution for a few seconds before continueing?

```
import maya.mel as mm
import maya.cmds as cmds
import time, os

# create something to add a node to
cmds.polySphere(sx=10, sy=15, r=20)
# add vray displacement node
mm.eval('vray objectProperties add_single VRayDisplacement;')
# add to displacement node
mm.eval('vray addAttributesFromGroup vrayDisplacement vray_subdivision 1;')
mm.eval('vray addAttributesFromGroup vrayDisplacement vray_displacement 1;')
mm.eval('vray addAttributesFromGroup vrayDisplacement vray_subquality 1;')
# connect filenode to displacement v-ray node
cmds.shadingNode('file',asTexture=1,n='displacement_file')
cmds.connectAttr('displacement_file.outColor', 'vrayDisplacement.displacement')
#cmds.pause( sec=2 )
cmds.refresh(su=1)
cmds.refreshEditorTemplates
#time.sleep(5) # have to sleep because maya needs to update the vray node with the new     attributes
# edit settings for displacement node
cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.overrideGlobalDisplacement', 1)
cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.vrayDisplacementKeepContinuity', 1)
cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.vray2dDisplacementFilterTexture', 0)
cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.vrayDisplacementAmount', 1.3)
cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.vrayEdgeLength', 6)
cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.vrayMaxSubdivs', 4)
```

I tried:

```
cmds.pause( sec=2 )
cmds.refresh(su=1)
cmds.refreshEditorTemplates
time.sleep(5)
```

none of these worked out.
the error I get is:

```
Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 22: setAttr: No object matches name: vrayDisplacement.vrayDisplacementKeepContinuity #
```

Comment: If that is so, than why would the first `setAttr` run? It is modifying an attribute of 'vrayDisplacement' after all. Have you tried commenting out `cmds.setAttr('vrayDisplacement.vrayDisplacementKeepContinuity', 1)` and seeing what happens? Maybe its not entirely spelled that way. Just a suggestion of course. I haven't gotten around to playing with vray yet...

Comment: Have you tried running this with the attribute editor closed?

Comment: The only reason why overrideGlobalDisplacement works is because it is not an attribute that is beeing added during excecution of the script. The others are though. I tried closing the attribute editor and commenting out the vrayDisplacementKeepContinuity, but then maya complains about the next one, filtertex. I somehow need to have python stop, then start again after maya had time to update. I guess that the last resort would be to have the user run the script twice, but I would like to be able to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s a weird things in maya. You have to use cmds.evalDeffered() to wrap your cmds.setAttr to delay it.

Comment: this thread seems to bear that out: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python_inside_maya/O3miKIce7Ws
However, setting things up such that adding attributes takes a 7 second delay to complete is just bad practice.